# Joins in Pig with pattern match

Tags: apache-pig

I have 2 files file1 and file2.

The contents of file1 are:
aa
bb
cc

The contents of file2 are:
aab f2 f3
zzx f2 f3
bbc f2 f3

I would like to join file1 (on field 1) and file2 (on field 1) using Pig where the output is:
aa aab f2 f3
bb bbc f2 f3

Basically, the match must be something similar to aa*, bb*, cc* etc.

Any ideas on how to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to use the `CROSS` operator followed by a `FILTER`.

```
input1 = LOAD 'file1' AS (f1:chararray, f2, f3);
input2 = LOAD 'file2' AS (f1:chararray, f2, f3);

crossed = CROSS input1, input2;
filtered = FILTER crossed BY INDEXOF(input2::f1, input1::f1) == 0;
```

`INDEXOF` is a built-in UDF that searches for the second string within the first one and returns the index of the first occurrence, or -1 if it does not occur.  Since you want the second string to begin with the first one, you are looking for an index of 0.

See the "Cross" section of the ["Advanced Pig Latin"](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/advanced_pig_latin.html) chapter of the excellent book Programming Pig.  In particular note the warning about `CROSS` generating large amounts of data.  If you have large inputs, you may wish to formulate an application-specific way of constructing a join key so that you do not require fuzzy matching.